# IMAP/POP Service with API

Tags: api, email, hosting, cloud-hosting

I work with a web design company and we're looking to streamline the provision and changes of email hosting we organise for our customers.

We'd like to use an API where we can create a postoffice (users@domain) and add/edit/delete users with forwarding/aliases etc. etc.

Anyone come across a hosting company that provides IMAP/POP services with a fully featured API?

Comment: Moderators if you don't consider this a programming question feel free to suggest where I stick a question of this nature.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is going to be heavily dependent on what email service you're using. For example, Google Apps offers email management as part of their Admin SDK API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/

If you're looking for a full-fledged email service, Google Apps may do it. However, it's a bit spendy: http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html

Other alternatives you might check out is Fusemail: https://www.fusemail.com/support/api-documentation/requests

If you're self-hosting and don't mind cPanel, they have an API as well:
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiEmail#Email::addforward